# Formally find inverse of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you find the inverse of a function formally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, finding the inverse graphically is not a formal justification. This may be what they are refering to.

Comment: Well that answer how *not* to do it.  It doesn't answer how *to* do it.